# How can I change this regex to allow searching by numbers as well?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help with regular expressions.  I borrowed this code from somewhere else, and it's working fine.  All that I need to do is capture a search text, then replace any symbols with the written text, if those symbols exist.  However I need to allow the user to search using numbers and decimals, for example search for invoices in the amount of 447.23 but its returning an "undefined".

```
var symbols = {
                    "$": "_dollar_",
                    "@": "_at_",
                    "#": "_pound_",
                    "%": "_percent_",
                    "&": "_amper_",
                    "*": "_star_",
                    "(": "_lparen_",
                    ")": "_rparen_",
                    "+": "_plus_",
                    "-": "_minus_",
                    "=": "_equal_",
                    ".": "_period_",
                    "\'": "_singlequote_",
                    "\"": "_quote_",
                    ":": "_colon_",
                    ";": "_semicolon_",
                    " ": "_space_",
                    ",": "_comma_"
                };
```

How can I change this regular expression to allow numbers to be used in the search?  ANy help is appreciated. thanks.

```
var search_text = $("#container").val();
   search_txt = search_txt.replace(/[$@#%&*()+-=.\'\",\s]|gw|kw/g, function(s) {
                            return symbols[s];
                        });
```

Comment: Remove the `.` and the `,` from the `[]` - `[$@#%&*()+-=\'\"\s]`

Comment: still the same result :(

Comment: What do you search in? What exactly returns `undefined` from where? Do you think you cannot search for decimals because the period is getting replaced?

Comment: I use an input box and search the string the user inputs...the function() call is searching the object "symbol[]" for the symbols, and if a symbol is matched it replaces it with the text...if not I thought it would return the search text.  If I use letters it works great but anytime I add a number the "search_txt" variable puts "undefined" where the number would be.  for example, if I search for "mess9" it will return "messundefined"

Answer (score 0):

Now that I got you, you want

```
search_txt = search_txt.replace(/[$@#%&*()+\-=.'",\s]|gw|kw/g, function(s) {
    if (s in symbols)
        return symbols[s];
    else
        return s; // the input
});
```

You could also shorten it to `return symbols[s] || s` (if you don't have empty strings in `symbols`), but I'd suggest you just should put all the matched sequences in your `symbols` object (or reduce the set of matched chars). Currently, you have colons and semicolons in your object but don't match them, and you match `gw`, `kw` and various whitespaces which are not in `symbols`.

Btw, you don't need to escape the quotes in regular expression literal. Yet, in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) you will have to escape the hyphen/minus sign. Otherwise, it would denote a range like `a-z`, and in your case `+-=` does match any of `+,-./0123456789:;<=`.